# Can't access uploaded files through Firebase storage on web

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to access/download files that have been uploaded to Firebase storage but I can't figure out how to. Some of the files have a *create new access token* button under the storage location which gives me a link to the file on the web. Unfortunately, this is only a few files and seems to only be ones uploaded from localhost?

I can't find any reference to this on the documentation, this should be achievable through the Firebase dashboard?

I've tried setting the access rules to allow reads in all cases which hasn't helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, you're supposed to use [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl), as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), from within your web or mobile app to generate a download URL for use within your app.  Typically, the console is only used to revoke the tokens that enable to download of each file through that URL.

If that's not specifically what you're trying to do, perhaps you want to read up on other was to [make data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) in Cloud Storage.  The Firebase console is not really the best mechanism to manage downloadable content.